# How to grab first element in a python list and check if it is None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

How can I grab the first element in a list and check if it is None?

```
a = [None, None, 1234, 'Apple', 1]
b = [None, 4321, 'Cheese', 1]
```

I want to grab the first element in list a and list b and determine if their first values are None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if a[0] is None and b[0] is None: 
    # do your stuff
```

Comment: Thank you! this works as well. I like these different ways.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

- `a[0] is None`
  returns `True` if the first element in `a` is `None`.
- `a.pop(0) is None`
  returns `True` if the first element in `a` is `None` **and removes that element** from `a`.

## Grabbing the first element in a `list`

You can access the first element in a `list` by specifying `0` as an index:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x[0]
1
```

Specifying higher index numbers gives you the other elements, or an error if that index doesn't exist:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x[0]
1
>>> x[1]
2
>>> x[2]
3
>>> x[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Alternatively, you can simultaneously retrieve and remove an element from the `list` by using `pop()`:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x.pop()
3
>>> x
[1, 2]
```

Note that, without an argument, `pop()` returns the last element of the `list`, and removes it from the `list`.

With an argument (which is an index number), it will return (and remove) the specified element:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x.pop(0)
1
>>> x
[2, 3]
```

## Checking if a value is `None`

Simply use the `is None` comparison:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x[0] is None
False
>>> a = [None, None, 1234, 'Apple', 1]
>>> b = [None, 4321, 'Cheese', 1]
>>> a[0] is None
True
>>> b[0] is None
True
>>> a[0] is None and b[0] is None
True
```

Using `pop()`, which **will remove the specified element** from the `list`:

```
>>> a = [None, None, 1234, 'Apple', 1]
>>> b = [None, 4321, 'Cheese', 1]
>>> a.pop(0) is None and b.pop(0) is None
True
>>> a
[None, 1234, 'Apple', 1]
>>> b
[4321, 'Cheese', 1]
```

## Bonus: negative indices

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x[-1]
3
>>> x[-2]
2
>>> x[-3]
1
>>> x[-4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

A roundabout way of getting the first element. Not practical, just for fun:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x[len(x) * -1]
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if a[0] is None:
     print("The first element in list a is None")
else:
     print("The first element in list a is not None")
```

You can do the same to test the first element in list b.

Answer (score 0):

did you google this? this is a rather basic question.

```
if a[0] is None : print("is None")
else : print("is not none")
```

same for b

Comment: I did but I couldn't quite find an answer. I am very new to python.